# FreeRTOS on STM32F407-Discovery

Tags: freertos, stm32f4

I downloaded FreeRTOS port for STM32F4-Discovery from https://github.com/wangyeee/STM32F4-FreeRTOS and I managed to compile it and flash it to the board, but I don't know what to do next. I would like to verify that it is working.

I tried to use debugger and I saw that after reset the program is in function deregister_tm_clones and the board does nothing.

What to do next?

Thanks

Vaclav

Answer (score 1):

You have the code, so can look to see what it is doing.  Alternatively you can ask the author of the code by contacting them via github - if you do that they will see the question, if you post a question about there code here then it is unlikely they will see it.

Alternatively there are lots of resources available on the web to help you.  For example there is an (old) documented port to that chip on the FreeRTOS website here: https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-for-STM32F4xx-Cortex-M4F-IAR.html  ST's STM32Cube software will create FreeRTOS projects for you http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html - and if you just want to learn FreeRTOS you can download a free book here https://www.freertos.org/Documentation/RTOS_book.html

Comment: It's strange but I found the function deregister_tm_clones only in the elf file but not in the source.